# Regex: Python First Occurrence After Return or Newline

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match a set of data, and even while I can create the regex correctly, Python returns no match. I'd like to know if I'm formatting my regexes in Python correctly.

I'm trying to match the date after any \r or \n. It can be any of the following:

```
Date/Time Sep 12 11:13:42

Date/Time   Sep 12 11:13:42

Date/Time
Sep 12 11:13:42

Date/Time



Sep 12 11:13:42
```

And using the `(?<=Date/Time\s)(\r*[\w :]+)` works as far as any validator is concerned.

I input this as `date = re.findall("(?<=Date/Time\s)(\r*[\w :]+)", content)` however I never get any matches returned.

The regex is formatted correctly. My question is whether my regex is formatted incorrectly as far as **Python** is concerned (illegal characters, etc.)?

Comment: `Date/Time\s+(.*)` should suffice.

Comment: Also, can you read your input file and post the output of `print repr(contents)`?

Comment: @Blender, that does match with the 'Date/Time' string as well as the date. My method provides positive lookahead.

Comment: What difference does it make? As long as it matches the same strings, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But... it already works:

```
content = """\
Date/Time Sep 12 11:13:42

Date/Time   Sep 12 11:13:42

Date/Time
Sep 12 11:13:42

Date/Time



Sep 12 11:13:42"""

import re

re.findall("(?<=Date/Time\s)(\r*[\w :]+)", content)
#>>> ['Sep 12 11:13:42', '  Sep 12 11:13:42', 'Sep 12 11:13:42']
```

You should consider using `\n` instead of `\r`, though, to get that last date. Maybe even use `\s` to match any spacing.

Comment: That is where my confusion lies. Any validator I use matches my regex to the data input, but my actual program when run returns nothing. I have also tried '\n' with no avail.

Comment: That's what I'm curious about, however all other Regex's within my script return data.

Comment: Right. So you need to debug your script. *We* can't do it for you.

Comment: I was merely asking if my regex wasn't right as far as Python is concerned. Meaning is python catching a set of characters and parsing them incorrectly? I'm asking nobody to debug my script.

Comment: Yes. I decided to look for all whitespace characters instead. Which gives me '\n\r\nSep 12 11:13:42' however I can suffice with that.

Comment: If you want to not capture the `\n\r\n`, use `"(?<=Date/Time\s)\s*([\w :]+)"`.

Comment: Glad you caught that. Thanks!